# Ubuntu Mock URL to Hit Virtual Server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, subdomain, hosts

This is slightly difficult to explain, but I'm trying to mock a domain name on a virtual machine so that I can hit the subdomain. If you need any clarification, I would be happy to provide it.

The first layer is the Nginx server on Ubuntu. It's set up so that it points to two ports on a different server, api (192.168.0.26:3001) and web (192.168.0.26.3000). If I use the command `curl api.localhost` or `curl localhost` I get the correct output. This means that nginx is correctly configured and hitting the other server.

The occurs when I try to hit the nginx server. Let's say the IP for the server is 192.168.0.25. If I `curl 192.168.0.25` it hits the web server. Perfect, that's what I need. However, I can't `curl api.192.168.0.25` for obvious reasons. If I try it just doesn't work.

The OS that I'm using to try the nginx server is Ubuntu. I'm wondering if there's a way that I can assign the nginx IP address to a mock url, for example, test.com. This way, I'll be able to simulate how it would look online, so I'll be able to `curl api.test.com` and get the result that I want.

I've tried to add the IP to the /etc/hosts file, but that didn't seem to work. Is there a way that I can mock the domain on my local machine? If you need any clarification I'll be happy to provide it.

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed I do not understand this: "I've tried to add the IP to the /etc/hosts file, but that didn't seem to work." so I think you will need to show exactly what you put in the file and the error you got. Because if you add `192.168.0.25 api.test.com` then `curl api.test.com` should hit `192.168.0.25` but the server there should of course be configured to understand that it is indeed `api.test.com` and react accordingly. Also since it is not programming related this is kind of offtopic here, try instead [su] or [sf].

Comment: Hi Patrick. I'll make sure to try Super User or Server Fault. I just thought Stack Overflow was the "catch all" haha. Anyway, I've been researching and kinda figured it out but am left with this: the nginx server is correctly working. If i `curl api.localhost` I get the correct output. But when I go to my testing server (the one with the edited hosts file), if I try `curl api.test.com` I get the output from the web server, rather than the api server. The hosts file is `192.168.0.25 test.com api.test.com`. I'm not sure what to do from here.